# Does Princess Renner have other hidden personality as depicted in the 2nd season's ending credit?

Tags: overlord

From the ED song, it seems like the Princess has dark/other personality which we all don't know about.

Is it true? Is there any story of hers to begin with?

The specific scenes from the ending:

> [image: Princess Renner from ED]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems Princess Renner *does* have another personality. You can also confirm from the anime (Season 2 episode 09)

---

**Renner's Personality:**

> Renner is known publicly as the Golden Princess for her benevolence and kindness. While Renner is believed to be a saint, in reality, she has a **psychopathic personality** and doesn't care about the feelings of others. The only exception to this is Climb. When Climb was wounded, she declared that anyone involved would be ruthlessly killed. After being **secretly affiliated to Nazarick**, she doesn't hesitate to betray her family, her bloodline and her people without a shred of regret. Renner is a human yet inhuman and she's described as a spiritual heteromorph. Her mind comprehended both good and evil; she is the type who was not bound by the petty constraints of morality, but who calmly worked to advance her own agenda.

---

**Renner's relation with Climb:**

> Renner treats Climb like a pet dog and loves him greatly, as he is the reason she started to act innocent, kind and caring greatly about the country in front of him after picking him up. When Climb is not around, she reverts back to her **psychopathic personality**.

---

**Renner's relation with Albedo:**

> Aside from secretly being her subordinate, Renner is in a particularly friendly relationship with Albedo, openly talking with each other about the obsessive love they hold for the men they love.

---

Lastly a dialogue which will sums it all:

> "*Yes, it would indeed be difficult to do while putting up a front as Princess. Plus, there is no use if it's done by force. His gaze, I want to chain him up completely and raise him like a dog.*" - Renner to Marquis Raeven about Climb.

---

<sub>Source: [Renner Theiere Chardelon Ryle Vaiself - Overlord Wiki](http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Renner_Theiere_Chardelon_Ryle_Vaiself)</sub>

Comment: Good news, update your answer because the episode today showed it off